# I only have one Main method but I still get an error

Tags: c#

So I am fairly new to programming, and I was trying to enter some sample code into Visual Studio 2019, and getting the following error.

> Error code CS0017 : "Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point."

My code is below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace FirstProject
{
    /*
    class Program
    {
       // I had a main method here but i took it out and its still giving me the error :(
    } //end of class
    */
    public enum CarType
    {
        Toyota = 1,
        Honda = 2,
        Ford = 3,
    } //end of enum

    public class Tutorial
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CarType myCarType = CarType.Toyota;
            int a = 4;

            if (a == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A is equal to 4");
                Console.WriteLine("I don't know how to fix the error :(");
                //Console commands can only be run in the main method
            } //end of if statement
        } // end of main method
    } //end of class
} //end of namespace
```

Comment: i am not sure , but i think the entry point is program class that was commented i think you should rename Tutorial to Program.

Comment: It means there's some other class in the project that has a `public static void Main` method. It could be in a different file, or different namespace. Search the entire *project* for `Main`.

Comment: @Mr.AF that doesn't matter

Comment: Can you show us the markup from your .csproj file?

Comment: You should check the `Startup object` of the console project `Properties`: right click the proect -> *Properties* -> *Application* -> *Startup object*.

Comment: search `public static void Main` in your entire project and you will get the duplicate Main.

Comment: Thanks guys :D I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: That can also happen with a .NET Core project file that is capable of running unit tests. Even though there isn't more than one file with Main() in it, the error still happens. The solution is to separate the normal source files (and project file) from the unit test part (with a separate project file).

Answer (score 0):

I`m new to programming as well. I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by right clicking the error message CS0017 and choosing SILENT for the severity. I was then able to run my program.

[image]